# Creating performance profiles

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

A performance profile is a kind of plot used in the optimization community; here below is an example from http://www.gamsworld.com/performance. [image: http://www.gamsworld.org/performance/profileGnuplot.gif]

For an introduction, see [Section 22.4](http://books.google.it/books?id=h3L4mu4YnP8C&lpg=PA320&dq=higham%20higham%20performance%20profile&pg=PA320#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Higham and Higham's book *Matlab guide*. Informally speaking, the graph reports which percentage (on the `y` axis) of a number of experiments done with competing methods is within a certain threshold (on the `x` axis) of the best result.

A formal specification is as follows.

- Suppose you run m tests to compare n existing methods. Let r_{ij} be the result (error, computational time... whatever; let's say that lower is better) obtained by method j on test i.
- The *performance* of method j on test i is defined as the ratio between its result and the best result on the same test, p_{ij} = r_{ij} / (min_j r_{ij}). Note that p_{ij} \geq 1.
- The *performance function* of method j is the function f_j(x) = 1/m * (number of tests i such that p_{ij} \leq x), that is, the "probability" that the method j is within a factor x of the best possible method. Note that f_j(x) is (weakly) monotonically increasing in x for each j.
- A *performance profile* is the plot of all functions f_j, as in the image above.

Do you know if there is support for creating performance profiles in tex? It is a very simple plot of course, so one in principle could preprocess the data and return a set of (x,y) pairs ready for plotting, but it would cut one step if the plot logic could be implemented natively in tex.

I have found nothing in the manual of `pgfplots`, which was my no. 1 candidate.

If someone wishes to implement it, here is a set of sample data, in pgfplots table format (method in columns, different tests in rows):

```
table{
  ode23    ode45   ode113
  1.26e-2  6.20e-3 1.56e-2
  2.41e-1  1.53e-1 1.97e-1
  3.74e-2  5.00e-2 6.68e-2
  3.37e0   6.45e0  7.86e0
  1.44e-1  1.56e-1 3.76e-2
  5.06e-1  1.07e0  1.5e0  
}
```

The output should look more or less like this image from the Higham & Higham book:

[image]

Comment: I think we will need some idea of the nature of the raw input here. As you say, the way the example plot appears seems just to use a list of value pairs, for which plotting is pretty trivial.

Comment: And beside of the input you should tell us an exemplary formula which you want to plot. I think just very few people are having time to read about performance plots in order to help you with this. Tell us a raw data example and a specific formula and I guess you will get a nice plot soon... Thanks.

Comment: I did not put an exact description because my question was "is there a package that does them out-of-the-box?". Now I realize that someone probably plans to quickly implement one in an answer, which would be awesome --- I love how everyone in this community really does a lot of work to help people. I'll edit my post adding formulas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are clearly a mathematician or something pretty close since your sentences are always inverted in an (ε, δ) way. You have to read the math backwards but the sentence forwards to decode :P

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10,
             perf name table/.default=mytable}
\pgfplotstableread{
  ode23    ode45   ode113
  1.26e-2  6.20e-3 1.56e-2
  2.41e-1  1.53e-1 1.97e-1
  3.74e-2  5.00e-2 6.68e-2
  3.37e0   6.45e0  7.86e0
  1.44e-1  1.56e-1 3.76e-2
  5.06e-1  1.07e0  1.5e0  
}\mytable

\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\mytable}% How many columns
\edef\mylastj{\number\numexpr\pgfplotsretval-1}% From zero to this num

%=========== Get the min of rows into a separate column =====================
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign/.code={%
    \def\myrowmin{1e10}% Some big number that will be ignored in any min() invocation
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x in {0,...,\mylastj}{%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}% To handle big numbers
    \pgfmathparse{min(\myrowmin,\thisrowno{\x})}%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    \let\myrowmin=\pgfmathresult%
    }%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\myrowmin%
  }
]{minperf}\mytable

%=========== Get each performance into a separate column =====================
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\mylastj}{
  \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/assign/.code={%
      \pgfmathparse{\thisrowno{#1}/\thisrow{minperf}}%
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfmathresult%
    }
  ]{perf-#1}\mytable
}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{colleqx}{2}{%
    \begingroup%
    \c@pgf@countd=0% No rows satisfy yet
    \pgfmathfloattoint{#1}%
    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{perf-\pgfmathresult}\of\mytable\as\mycompval{%
      \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\mycompval}%
      \pgfmathfloatlessthan{\pgfmathresult}{#2}%
      \ifpgfmathfloatcomparison\advance\c@pgf@countd by1\fi%
    }%
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mytable}%
    \pgfmathparse{\c@pgf@countd/\pgfplotsretval}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
    \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}\noindent
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\mytable} % Let's see if minperf and perffun-i works? 

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title=Performances,height=6cm]
        \addplot+[const plot] table[,x expr=\coordindex, y=perf-0] {\mytable};
        \addplot+[const plot] table[,x expr=\coordindex, y=perf-1] {\mytable};
        \addplot+[const plot] table[,x expr=\coordindex, y=perf-2] {\mytable};
        \legend{ode23,ode45,ode113}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title=Performance Functions,height=6cm,
                 legend pos=outer north east,grid=both,no marks]
        \addplot+[const plot,domain=1:5] (x,{colleqx(0,x)});
        \addplot+[const plot,domain=1:5] (x,{colleqx(1,x)});
        \addplot+[const plot,domain=1:5] (x,{colleqx(2,x)});
        \legend{ode23,ode45,ode113}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code leads to the following result

[image]

Some remarks;

1. What I did is first compute the performances and add them as columns as you can see from the first table.
2. Then I wrote a small math function which hides the table access macros and counting stuff such that it looks like a math function when `pgfplots` calls it but it is actually a counting function within each column. When you call it `colleqx(<column index>,<x value>)` (for **number of rows of column index than or equal to x**) it would give you the formula you provided for `j = <column index>`. Index numbering starts at zero.
3. The whole mechanism is based on the table name `\mytable`. Because otherwise I know that I would spend a whole evening on it. I have to leave it to you :) However it works with arbitrary number of cols and rows (I hope).

---

It always breaks my heart to see someone as proficient as N. Higham spends energy on things like matlab but not a proper programming language. Anyway, I digress.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll try to understand your code, the structure looks clear. Yes, indeed I am a mathematician, spotted. :)

Comment: @percusse: Or you could use the built-in `performance` plot type, of course. `;-)`

Comment: @Jake To be honest for a few seconds I thought about opening the manual haha.