# How to pass a function defined in sagetex to pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, sagetex

Is there any way to pass a function defined in sagtex to pgfplots for plotting? See the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{sagetex}


\begin{document}

\begin{sagesilent}
  f(x) = 2*sin(x^2)
\end{sagesilent}

$f(x) = \sage{f(x)}$

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[no markers, samples=100]
%      \addplot gnuplot {\sageraw{f(x)}};
      %should be the same as
      \addplot gnuplot {2*sin(x^2)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I also tried `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{function}{\sagestr{print(f(x))}}` and then `\addplot gnuplot {function(x)};` but it didn't work.

**Edit 2:** I have just opened a feature request for sagetex: https://github.com/dandrake/sagetex/issues/1 I hope there will be a solution for this issue soon

Comment: Declare a math function, `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{generic sage}` with one argument. Assign the output to the raw sage output. I don't have Sage so I can't test it.

Comment: How can I get the "raw sage output"? The command `\sageraw` above doesn't exist, it was only a fake command.

Comment: Can't you run the sage output with `sagesilent` within the function declaration?

Comment: You don't need gnuplot there,  the function should only call sagetex retrieve a value and assign it. For example here, I'm calling table macros to retrieve values etc. and assigning to the output as if it was a math function http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197349/3235

Comment: @percusse Can you post a minimal working example to make more clear what you mean?

Comment: I ran into this problem some time back and I don't think there is a simple answer. I've worked along the lines that percusse suggests; i.e., getting the raw output. I've posted several examples on this site: [Riemann zeta](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220552/how-do-you-plot-the-riemann-zeta-function-using-tikz-pgfplot) [Cantor function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241622/plotting-the-cantor-function), [Fourier](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240425/drawing-fourier-expansion-using-pgfplots/240452#240452) and Weierstrass (not enough characters for that link).

Comment: @percusse You don't need Sage to test. Just open a free [Sagemath Cloud account](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) to get access to Sage, LaTeX, and a lot more. Extremely powerful--think you'd find it useful!

Comment: @DJP Quite true. I'm not too familiar with the *hip* tools of CAS systems. But I actually wrote a control systems toolbox on Python with some influence of these **free** tools. I actually selected Python after hearing it from my Sage-junkie colleagues. Can you maybe write an answer for this?

Comment: @percusse 3 comments above I mentioned 4 examples that I posted on this site. The method looks different than the link you posted but the idea of getting the data and plotting is essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have sage installed, but give it a try...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
x=var('x')
y=var('y')
x_coords = [x for x in srange(0,10)]
y_coords = [2*sin(x*x) for x in srange(0,10)]
output = ""
for i in range(0,len(x_coords)-1):
    output+=r"\draw[red, thick] (%f cm ,%f cm)--(%f cm ,%f cm);"%(x_coords[i],y_coords[i],x_coords[i+1],y_coords[i+1])
\end{sagesilent}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymax=2]
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
\sagestr{output}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

maybe you have to adapt the example which was used from  http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/sagetex.html

But I cannot test it at the moment...

Comment: Is this code working?

Comment: Yes it works after I fixed some minor mistakes. But it seems to complicated, it is not exactly what I want.

Comment: Sorry for that, I only tried to solve the problem without the possibility to test the code.