# Drawing gamma function in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Is there an elegant way to plot gamma function (or some similar non-elementary function),

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

via TikZ or pgfplots? The graph I have in mind is something similar to the following one,

http://intmath.com/blog/wp-content/images/2010/05/gamma-4.gif

The only solution that falls to my mind is the calculation of a list of coordinates (x,\Gamma(x)) with some other (non-TeX) software and then plotting those, but I would like to know if it is possible to avoid this path.

Comment: Hello. Have you tried searching this forum (or anywhere else on the web) for ways how to plot a function in LaTeX?

Comment: TikZ has a set of built-in (predefined) elementary functions (such as exp, ln, sin, etc.) so there is no problem with those. I'm note sure if there is some other way to draw \Gamma(x), apart from e.g. generating the coordinates (x,\Gamma(x)) with some other software, and then plotting those in TikZ or pgf?

Comment: Well, the it would be nice to show your effort, or to be more specific. This way it looks like you didn't search at all. And no, I don't think that the gamma function exists...

Comment: @IvicaSmolić: Search for "gamma function" on this site and you should find what you are looking for, or at least those will help you get started.

Comment: @PeterGrill: All the examples that I've managed to dig up at the TeX.stack fall either in a) functions definable via elementary functions or b) plotting of the list of coordinates. My hope was that there exists a "third path", whatever that might be.

Comment: I'd try `gnuplot`. It has an implementation of the gamma function.

Comment: Using essentially the same code I posted for [plotting the zeta function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220552/how-do-you-plot-the-riemann-zeta-function-using-tikz-pgfplot), you can plot gamma. You need to import that function, though, as is done [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/functions/sage/functions/other.html).

Comment: @1010011010 I'd support your choice (see [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.3/prob.html))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an elegant way… with the `pst-func` package:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}

\usepackage{pst-func}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1.25cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-4.8,-4.8)(4.8,4.8)
\psaxes[ticksize=2pt -2pt]{->}(0,0)(-4.8,-4.8)(4.8,4.8)[$ x $, -120][$ y $, -140]
\psset{linecolor=Tomato3,linewidth=1.2pt,plotpoints=100,algebraic}
\psplot{-4.995}{-4.005}{GAMMA(x)}
\psplot{-3.995}{-3.01}{GAMMA(x)}
\psplot{-2.99}{-2.05}{GAMMA(x)}
\psplot{-1.95}{-1.05}{GAMMA(x)}
\psplot{-0.9}{-0.1}{GAMMA(x)}
\psplot{.1}{5.8}{GAMMA(x)}
\psset{linewidth = 0.6pt, linecolor = LightSteelBlue3}
\multido{\i=-4+1}{4}{\psline(\i, -5.8)(\i, 5.8)}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose the implication is that `GAMMA` is a built-in function? neat!

Comment: It's defined in the `pst-math` module, that called by `pst-func`. Also defined: `GAMMALN`.

Comment: @Bernard: Absolutely great! I couldn't ask for more elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**1. With pgfplots and gnuplot:**

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\begin{axis}[
xmin = -4.9, xmax = 5.1, 
%ymin = -3.5, ymax = 3.5,  
restrict y to domain=-6:6,
axis lines = middle,
axis line style={-latex},  
xlabel={$x$}, 
ylabel={$y$},
%enlarge x limits={upper={val=0.2}},
enlarge y limits=0.05,
x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.00)}, inner sep=5pt, anchor=north},
y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.00)}, inner sep=2pt, anchor=south east},
]

\addplot[color=red, samples=222, smooth, 
domain = 0:5] gnuplot{gamma(x)};

\foreach[evaluate={\N=\n-1}] \n in {0,...,-5}{%
\addplot[color=red, samples=555, smooth,  
domain = \n:\N] gnuplot{gamma(x)};
%
\addplot [domain=-6:6, samples=2, densely dashed, thin] (\N, x);
}%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**2. Only pgfplots as [an approximation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammafunktion#Stirlingsche_Formel):**

[image]

We can see a good accordance with the exact gnuplot-curve:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
xmin =0, xmax = 5.1, 
%ymin = -3.5, ymax = 3.5,  
restrict y to domain=-6:6,
axis lines = middle,
xlabel={$x$}, 
ylabel={$y$},
enlarge x limits=0.05,
enlarge y limits=0.1,
x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.00)}, inner sep=5pt, anchor=north},
y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.00)}, inner sep=2pt, anchor=south east},
]
\addplot[color=blue, samples=222, smooth, 
domain = 0:5] {sqrt(2*pi)*x^(x-0.5)*exp(-x)*exp(1/(12*x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The Gamma function is also built in [Asymptote.](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) Here is a reproduction of Bernard's graph with this program.

```
import graph;
unitsize(1.5cm);
real Xmin=-5, Xmax=5, Ymin=-5, Ymax=5;
// Graphs
for (real x = Xmin; x < 0; x=x+1) {draw(graph(gamma, x+0.001, x+0.999), red);};
draw(graph(gamma, 0.1, Xmax), red);
// Clipping (cut the parts beyond the borders)
clip((Xmin, Ymin) -- (Xmax, Ymin) -- (Xmax, Ymax) -- (Xmin, Ymax) -- cycle);
// Asymptotes (no pun here)
for (real x=Xmin; x<0; x=x+1) {draw((x, Ymin)--(x, Ymax), 0.8*white);};
// Axes
xaxis(xmin=Xmin, xmax=Xmax, Ticks(Step=1, OmitTick(0, Xmax)), arrow=Arrow);
yaxis(ymin=Ymin, ymax=Ymax, Ticks(Step=1, OmitTick(0, Ymin, Ymax)), arrow=Arrow);
```

[image: Gamma function]