# How to plot factorial function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm quite new to tikz and pgf. I'm plotting Big O time complexities and after looking at enough examples I've been able to create exactly the graphs I want with the exception of the factorial. Simply plotting x! creates this weird stair-step graph. I'd like it to be a smooth curve. I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371255/plot-a-factorial-function) which has an answer of using `semilogyaxis`. However simply switching to that doesn't help, the factorial graph looks the same. I also tried to do an entirely new plot following the example answer in the question and it did overlay but the factorial graph looked incorrect, I assume it has to do with the logarithmic y axis and I'm not sure how to adjust the coordinates. I just need something like `f(x) = x!` which should produce a graph like below:

[image: Desired Factorial Graph]

**Here is an MWE of what I have so far:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    grid = major,
    clip = true,
    ticks = none,
    width=0.8\textwidth,
    height=0.6\textwidth,
    every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
    axis line style = ultra thick,
    clip mode=individual,
    restrict y to domain=0:10,
    restrict x to domain=0:10,
    axis x line = left,
    axis y line = left,
    domain = 0.00:10,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 11,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 11,
    xlabel = n,
    ylabel = no. of operations,
    xlabel style = {at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=south},
    ylabel style = {at={(axis description cs:-0.08,0.5)},anchor=north},
    label style = {font=\LARGE\bf},
  ]
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{x^2}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n^2)$};
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
]
{x}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n)$};
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=orange,
]
{log2 x}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(\log{}n)$};
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=black,
]
{x*(log2 x)}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n\log{}n)$};
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=magenta,
]
{1}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(1)$};
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=cyan,
]
{x^3}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n^3)$};

%Creates stair-step like plot
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=green,
]{x!}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n!)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Which produces the following plot:**

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: The factorial is not wrong -as normal non-extended factorial is only defined for integers. You probably want the Gamma function `x! = Γ(x + 1)` that is indeed continuous - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224118/drawing-gamma-function-in-latex

Comment: I also came across that question, but I'm couldn't figure out how to merge it with my existing plots. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recreate the @haver solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520121/8650 for the Gamma function with OP code - to help people searching for continuous factorial. The real factorial is only defined for integers - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial . `x! = Γ(x + 1)`

This solution needs `gnuplot` and `--shell-escape` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    grid = major,
    clip = true,
    ticks = none,
    width=0.8\textwidth,
    height=0.6\textwidth,
    every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
    axis line style = ultra thick,
    clip mode=individual,
    restrict y to domain=0:10,
    restrict x to domain=0:10,
    axis x line = left,
    axis y line = left,
    domain = 0.00:10,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 11,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 11,
    xlabel = n,
    ylabel = no. of operations,
    xlabel style = {at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=south},
    ylabel style = {at={(axis description cs:-0.08,0.5)},anchor=north},
    label style = {font=\LARGE\bf},
  ]
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{x^2}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n^2)$};
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
]
{x}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n)$};
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=orange,
]
{log2 x}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(\log{}n)$};
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=black,
]
{x*(log2 x)}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n\log{}n)$};
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=magenta,
]
{1}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(1)$};
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=cyan,
]
{x^3}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n^3)$};

%Creates stair-step like plot
\addplot [
    samples=100, 
    color=green,
]{x!}node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n!)$};

\addplot [
  samples=100,
  color=green, 
] gnuplot{gamma(x+1)} node[above,pos=1,style={font=\Large}]{$\mathcal{O}(n!)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph including Gamme(x+1)]

Comment: This small interval is not suitable to show the fast growth of `n!`

Comment: yeah I was wondering about that for a moment then I realized. Thanks!