# Inequality plot with PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to draw the inequality plot of this inequality but did not mange to find a way. The plot I want is similar to the one that Mathematica produces. Anybody can help?

[image]

I tried this command

```
\addplot3 [surf,shader=interp,samples=45, domain=-2:6, y domain=-2:6]
{(3*sqrt(x^2+y)+sqrt(4*x^3-3*x^2+y)-4)/(sqrt(y+1)+sqrt(3)*sqrt(4*x^3+3*y-  1)-4)};
```

and then `view={0}{90}` but it takes a lot of time to compile and I guess there should be a way to produce a 2D plot rather than changing the angle of a 3D plot.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: pgfplots can't work as a CAS system as mathematica does. You have to either come up with a closed form for your expressions or import the data. Otherwise no.

Comment: Why can't you just export the plot as PDF form Mathematica and include that in LaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and easy way is to use the CAS Sage, along with the `sagetex` package with code something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
H =region_plot((3*sqrt(x^2+y)+sqrt(4*x^3-3*x^2+y)-4)/(sqrt(y+1)+sqrt(3)*sqrt(4*x^3+3*y-1)-4)<=1,(x,-3,5),(y,-3,5),incol='lightblue', bordercol='gray',plot_points=500)
\end{sagesilent}
\sageplot[width=6cm]{H}
\end{document}
```

Run the code through a free [SagemathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) account to get this output.
[image]
Documentation on region_plot can be found [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/plot/contour_plot.html) on the Sage website.
I think it's possible to force this type of plot through pgfplots but it would take a lot more time. If that's what you want you can find some related posts on this site (search plot and sagetex) such as the `sagetex` solutions for [Riemann Zeta](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220552/how-do-you-plot-the-riemann-zeta-function-using-tikz-pgfplot) and [Cantor Function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241622/plotting-the-cantor-function).

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right that using pgfplots takes a lot of time. But by any chance, do you know why my current method (using a 3D plot and then changing the view) is very slow?

Comment: I don't know. I think the reason is what percusse comments above: it's not a CAS system so not designed to efficiently perform lots of complicated calculations. Which is what makes using Sage, sagetex and LaTeX such a powerful combination: an actual CAS does the math and LaTeX takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `pgfplots` and use `compat=newest` which should enable the Lua backend for faster function evaluation.  However, the compile time is still several minutes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    view={0}{90},
    samples=101,
    domain=-2:6,
    y domain=-2:6,
    restrict z to domain=-inf:1,
    xmin=-2, xmax=6,
    ymin=-2, ymax=6,
    ]

    \addplot3 [surf,shader=interp]
    {
      (3*sqrt(x^2+y)+sqrt(4*x^3-3*x^2+y)-4)
      /
      (sqrt(y+1)+sqrt(3)*sqrt(4*x^3+3*y-1)-4)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]