# Nesting sagetex in animate for tikz (and asymptote) gif - possible or impossible?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, animate, sagetex

I am running Windows 10 or 11 (I don't know), have WSL2 running on my system - Ubuntu distribution, and have SageMath downloaded on my computer. I have successfully established contact between all three softwares, and have been able to run .tex files containing Sage code.

From the Ubuntu terminal, I run:

1. `cd /mnt/c/users/myname`
2. `pdflatex filename.tex`
3. `sage filename.sagetex.sage`
4. `pdflatex filename.tex`

I would like to make a TikZ (or asymptote, but that's more complicated and I believe it probably legitimately requires the python method mentioned below) animation which is based on math that is beyond TeX's capabilities, using the sagetex package. I am having trouble getting this to work and would like some advice. Worst case scenario would be making a Python script to rewrite the whole document for each frame - without using the animate package, then append them together using ImageMagick or something - which is okay if I need to. All I care about is the product; I do not care how long it takes for my computer to make it.

Here is a Minimal non-Working Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{sagetex,animate,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{sageblock}
    f(x) = x
\end{sageblock}
\begin{animateinline}[palindrome]{1}
\multiframe{10}{x=0+1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (\sage{f(\x)},0);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Please tell me; can I make this work for tikz, or is the Python script option the better way to go? I don't think I need to ask about whether this would work for asymptote, lol :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach in the code above, using the `animate` package **in LaTeX** doesn't work because your LaTeX code includes the code `\sage{f(\x)}`. For the `sagetex` package to work your document has compile properly in your step 2 (`pdflatex filename.tex`). Since `Sage` won't run until step 3, and that missing content/calculation is necessary to construct the plot in step 2, LaTeX compilation fails. That's the essential reason why, in many of my answers for `sagetex` problems, I create a string of LaTeX code that is then inserted into the LaTeX document on your step 4. For example, see my answer to [How do you plot the Riemann Zeta function using Tikz/Pgfplot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220552/how-do-you-plot-the-riemann-zeta-function-using-tikz-pgfplot/220656#220656). However, I don't see how this approach can work with the `animate` package **in LaTeX**. I think you could with a lot of time and effort use the `animate` command **in Sage** to create an animated .gif. That would involve creating the Tikz images using Sage along with the `animate` command **in Sage**. Your list of graphics objects would in Sage's `animate` code would be the Tikz images. I think this would significantly increase the time/complexity in creating the animated gif. If it were me, I would construct the animation using Sage plotting along with Sage `animate'.
To illustrate that approach, go to the [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/). Copy/paste the code below into the box. Then press the 'Evaluate' button as shown in the picture. You will see Sage run the animation.

```
def Rotate(A,P,degrees):
    A1 = [A[0]-P[0],A[1]-P[1]]
    theta = degrees*pi/180
    R = [A1[0]*cos(theta)-A1[1]*sin(theta), A1[0]*sin(theta)+A1[1]*cos(theta)]
    return [R[0]+P[0],R[1]+P[1]]

L=[]
for j in range(1,15):
    G = Graphics()
    N = j
    Start = [1,0]
    Finish = [0,0]
    Curve = [[1,0], [0,0]]
    n = 1

    while n<N:
        CurveR=[]
        for i in range(0,len(Curve)-1):
            CurveR += [Rotate(Curve[i],Curve[len(Curve)-1],-90)] 
        for i in range(len(CurveR)-1,-1,-1):    
            Curve += [CurveR[i]]
        n += 1
    G += line(Curve)
    L += [G.plot()]
d=animate([L[k]for k in range(1,14)],xmin=-22,xmax=87,ymin=-44,ymax=90,axes=False)

d.show(delay=100)
```

The result is the animation in the picture below:

[image]

You can download the `gif` by right clicking on the image. With respect to your code above, I think this code is closer to what you wrote:

```
f(x)=x
L=[]
for j in range(0,15):
    G = Graphics()
    Curve = line([(0,0), (f(j),0)])

    G += Curve
    L += [G.plot()]
d=animate([L[k]for k in range(1,14)],xmin=0,xmax=15,ymin=0,ymax=2,axes=False)

d.show(delay=100)
```

You can see the result of right clicking it below:

[image]

Creating the animation using only Sage should be relatively quick and easy. To have an animation of Tikz images, the line `L += [G.plot()]` would have to be modified to include, png/pdf Tikz plots that have already been created (extra steps) or are created on the fly (lots of extra coding). So I suspect you could adapt `animate` **in Sage** to create an animation of Tikz pictures but that's a lot more complicated and time consuming to do.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response; this will be helpful to people in the future trying to navigate the same problem. In the end I decided to ditch the animate package completely and just use Python to do the math and make each "frame." Then I just appended the frames together in a gif. Since Sage is Python-based, this is most likely accomplishable in Sage as well. Thanks again for your response. Basically, I used a for loop instead of `animate`.